# Intent between 2 fragments not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm using Fragments in my app. One of them has a listView, and when I do a setOnItemClickListener, I want to pass the item clicked to the other fragment...
Here's the class OngletCours where I do my Intent:

```
   l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           Intent  a = new Intent(getActivity(), OngletNotes.class);


           startActivity(a);
       }

   });


    return rootView;
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to do an Intent to go to another Fragment:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.dasilvadd.students/com.example.dasilvadd.students.OngletNotes}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Student"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".PageAccueil">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Inscription"
        android:label="Student" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Onglets"

        android:label="Student"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Reglages" />
    <activity android:name=".MotDePasse" />



    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

I've already tried to add it by myself, but it doesnt recognize the class I created for the Second Fragment (OngletNotes).

Please tell me how to solve this. And thank you in advance !

Comment: Is `OngletNotes` a `Fragment`? I don't see that one in the manifest. You can not start a Fragment without an Activity where it's attached.

Comment: You are trying open a new Activity (OngleNotes).

Comment: Yes OngletNnotes is a Fragment, so how do I do fix it ?

Comment: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? read this, `OngletNotes` add this activity in manifest

Comment: Do you want to start a new Activity with the new Fragment or swap the current Fragment?

Comment: I want to be able to swap between my 2 fragments

Answer (score 2):

If you start OngletNotes using startActivity, I assume it's an Activity. In that case you need to add it to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".OngletNotes"
    android:label="Notes" />
```

If OngletNotes is a Fragment, it should be put inside of the Activity. You can't launch standalone Fragment without an Activity.

1. You need to create an Activity (don't forget to put it in `AndroidManifest.xml`)
2. Put your Fragment inside of the Activity (in xml or programmatically)
3. Start the Activity using startActivity

Comment: Well, I use startActivity because I've learned like that to swap betweent activites, but in my case OngletNotes is a fragment..

Comment: Fragment can't be launched like this. Fragment must be inside of the Activity. If you want to keep a Fragment, the solution would be to place Fragment inside of the Activity and start the Activity or replace current fragment with the new one in current activity. This is how to replace a fragment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace

Answer (score 0):

@ Update: OngletNotes is a fragment

Fragment example:

```
    public static OngletNotes newInstance(/* input parameters if any */) {
        OngletNotes fragment = new OngletNotes();
        // put values which you want to pass to fragment
        // Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ongletNotes, container, false);
        // if you have passed some data above
        // Bundle args = getArguments();
        return view;
    }
```

============================================================

@ Update: 
First, your onCreate in MainActivity,

```
// create a new instance of OngletCours (example is shown above)
OngletCours OngletCoursFragment = OngletCours.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, OngletCoursFragment )
    .commit();

// and your OnItemClickListener
l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                OngletNotes targetFragment = OngletNotes.newInstance();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, targetFragment)
                        .commit();
            }

        });
```

activity_main.xml: you shoud have a FrameLayout which is used as a container to switch fragments

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I'm still not able to swap to the 2nd Fragment (OngletNotes), but the content appears in the 1st Fragment (OngletCours), which is very weird I think.

Comment: Can the first fragment (OngletCours) show in the activity, sush as MainActivity?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking for..

But when I launch my app, i have to log in to access OngletCours, which is the default Fragment.

Comment: is the ListView l1 in Fragment OngletCours or same level as the FrameLayout?

Comment: Yes, my Fragment OngletCours works perfectly, but when I click on an Item in my ListView, instead of swapping to the 2nd Fragment (OngletNotes), it shows the content of that 2nd Fragment in my 1st Fragment (OngletCours)...

Comment: don't you want the 1st Fragment replaced by 2nd Fragment?

Comment: Yes I do. I forgot to precise that my fragments are in a TabbedActivity.. does it change anything ?

Comment: I see, it is totally difference.
I think you should open a new question with more precise wordings, such as TabLayout , ViewPager,

Comment: I was away for the weekend sorry. Where do I insert this ? `OngletCours OngletCoursFragment = OngletCours.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, OngletCoursFragment )
    .commit();`

Answer (score 0):

After readed your last comment I have edited my aswer:

Open the fragment:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setCurrentItem (1, true);
        }
    });
```

In your `MainActivity` which contains `ViewPager` For example `private ViewPager mViewPager;` you need `setCurrentItem` method:

```
public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}
```

I suppose that OngleNotes fragment is the second fragment. That's why I send a 1 as a parameter.

Comment: Inside `onItemClick`

Comment: I wrote a different answer.